# 2D data binning in matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, binning

I'm trying to bin some data with x and y coordinates however I am facing 2 challenges:

1. bin width in x and y dimensions
2. bin location ( where should the bin edge start)

I have some sensors that track a target. Each sensor gets the position of the target in 2D space, however due to reading errors, the position I get from each sensor is different. Therefore I would like to bin the readings and then maybe take the average of the readings in the bin to get the location of the target.

I was wondering if someone could recommend an approach to a possible solution or maybe a book about binning theory so that I could get an idea of how to tackle my problem

Comment: In image processing I use binning 2x2 as follows: `I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));J = (I(1:2:end,1:2:end)+I(2:2:end,1:2:end)+I(1:2:end,2:2:end)+I(2:2:end,2:2:end))/4;imshow(J)`

Comment: It might be easier than reading about binning theory, `histcounts2` lets you bin 2D data with a specified number of bins in each dimension and returns the edges also. If you want o specify your own edges you could get the span of your data and use `meshgrid` to generate your own edges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `histcounts2` to perform binning in 2D. To get bin locations you could take the 2D space of all your measurements and divide it in an nxn grid, (choose n as your wish). If the coordinates are saved in a 2 column matrix `P`

```
x = P(:,1); y = P(:,2)
xmax = max(x); xmin = min(x);
ymax = max(y); ymin = min(y);
N = 10; % Lets say number of bins we want
dx = (xmax - xmin) / (N-1);  dy = (ymax - ymin)/ (N-1); % N-1 will be clear in the next two lines
Xedges = xmin - dx/2 : dx : xmax + dx/2; % The outermost edges fall outside the range of data
Yedges = ymin - dy/2 : dy : ymax + dy/2; 
N = histcounts2(x,y,Xedges,Yedges)
```

Comment: I get how histcounts2 works, my problem is however that I don't know how to set the parameters for it. 

For example, the size of the bin, is it maybe based on the error variance in my readings? or is there something else I need to take into account. Something else is the bin location, it might be the case that I have 3 different readings and I need a bin that includes all the 3 points inside it, is there a way to be sure 100% that this might happen? Given that I have many targets plus some ghost points.